# Why this code does not copy image to char array?

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to copy an image to a char array. It is like in the documentation example, but does not work correctly. What's wrong with the code below?

```
char* getImage(char* path){
    ifstream image;
    image.open(path, ifstream::binary);

    image.seekg (0, ios::end);
    int n = image.tellg();
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    image.seekg (0, ios::beg);

    char* res = new char[n];

    image.read(res, n);

    if (image)
        std::cout << "all characters read successfully." << endl;

    printf("length = %d", strlen(res));
    cout<<res<<"\n\n";
    image.close();
    return res;
}
```

And the output of my program;

```
n = 6942
all characters read successfully.
length = 4
```

Comment: Your image is most probably not a nul-terminated string. `std::strlen` just chokes on the first zero byte, and `std::cout` won't be able to display anything meaningful either.

Comment: You specified the output of your program. It seems good. Did you expect it to output anything else?

Comment: The length of the image is `n`, not `strlen(res)`.  That's where your mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is faulty. `strlen` requires the argument to be a null terminated string, and returns the number of non-null characters before encountering the first null. I know of no image formats that are null terminated, so your char array probably isn't guaranteed to contain any null termination characters.

Inserting `res` into an output stream (such as `cout`) is likewise faulty because of the same requirement of null termination.

It appears that the fifth byte of your image file happens to have same representation as the null termination character, but that does not mean that the image wasn't copied.

`ifstream::gcount` can be used to query the number of read bytes, and `ostream::write` can be used to output the entire content of a character array that may or may not contain null termination characters.

---

PS. While technically correct, it is a very bad idea to create dynamic objects and return a bare pointer from the function. Memory leaks, or other bugs are very likely. I recommend using `std::vector` instead.